# Technology to minimize latency in real-time connection

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, webrtc, latency

I want to transmit some telemetry data from a car to a web-app. The hardware is taken care of already. It will send data every 100ms through an android device.

I was wondering what has lower latency, websockets (socket.io) or webrtc (Datachannel) ?

Thank you

Comment: Good question but please move to discussion forums instead of stack overflow :) [e.g http://meta.stackoverflow.com]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSockets works over TCP. Oriented to client and server communication.

[WebRTC DataChannel](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/datachannels/) works over UDP. It seems [safe to use.](http://iswebrtcreadyyet.com/) It is more oriented to peer2peer communication.

I don't think there is a massive difference in latency. It is up to you if you need reliable delivery (TCP) or not (UDP).